# How to check if stream in twitch.tv is on?

Tags: java, twitch

Here is code of my `getStream` method:

```
public static Twitch_Stream getStream(String channelname) {
        try {
            String json = API.readJsonFromUrl("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?channel=" + channelname);

            Twitch_Stream stream = new Twitch_Stream();
            if (json.equalsIgnoreCase("[]")) {
                stream.setOnline(false);
                return stream;
            }

            JsonArray jb = gson.fromJson(json, JsonArray.class);
            if (jb.size() != 0) {
                JsonObject jo = (JsonObject) jb.get(0);
                stream.setOnline(true);
                stream.load(jo);
            }

            return stream;
        } catch (Exception error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }
```

and here is code of Twitch_Stream class http://pastebin.com/3RX1L1cv

When I make something like this

```
Twitch_Stream streamer = Twitch_API.getStream("Jankos");
Bukkit.broadcastMessage("getName " + streamer.getName());
Bukkit.broadcastMessage(streamer.isOnline() + "");
```

`streamer.getName()` return `null` and `streamer.isOnline()` returns `false`, even when stream is on.

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Post your code in question. If it is too long to post here it means you didn't reduce your example only to parts needed by this question.

Comment: cannot open this link and check;/?

Comment: Purpose of Stack Overflow is not only to help you, but to help others with similar problems. If your links will break then your question will be useless for others.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what problem is in your code but simple workaround would be reading content from `"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + channel` which is JSON in format:

```
{
    "_links" : {
       //links to stream and channel
    },
    "stream" : {
       //details about current stream
    }
}
```

Now if value of `stream` key is `null` stream is off-line. If it is not null, it is on-line.

So your code can look like

```
public static void main(String[] argv) throws IOException {

    System.out.println(checkIfOnline("Jankos"));
    System.out.println(checkIfOnline("nightblue3"));

}

public static boolean checkIfOnline(String channel) throws IOException {
    String channerUrl = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + channel;

    String jsonText = readFromUrl(channerUrl);// reads text from URL
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);

    return !json.isNull("stream");
}

private static String readFromUrl(String url) throws IOException {
    URL page = new URL(url);
    try (Stream<String> stream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            page.openStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).lines()) {
        return stream.collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
    }
}
```

I used `JSONObject` from `org.json` library. I am also using Java 8 and its streams.

If you want to use `gson` you can use instead something like

```
public static boolean checkIfOnline(String channel) throws IOException {
    String channerUrl = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + channel;

    String jsonText = readFromUrl(channerUrl);// reads text from URL

    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonObject json = parser.parse(jsonText).getAsJsonObject();

    return !json.get("stream").isJsonNull();
}
```

If you don't have Java 8 you can rewrite code reading text from URL to something like

```
private static String readFromUrl(String url) throws IOException {
    URL page = new URL(url);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Scanner scanner = null;
    try{
        scanner = new Scanner(page.openStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
            sb.append(scanner.nextLine());
        }
    }finally{
        if (scanner!=null)
            scanner.close();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

or from what I see you can use your `API.readJsonFromUrl` instead of `readFromUrl`.

Comment: It is feature added in Java 8. You can find more info here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html. In short it is pipeline of operations you want to do on some elements.

Comment: I don't know. Are you using Java 8?

Comment: @dekros If you are using Eclipse or any other IDE it should be able to add this imports for you. Anyway these classes belong to `java.util.stream` package so use `import java.util.stream.Collectors;` and `import java.util.stream.Stream;`

Comment: i have this error http://scr.hu/1det/03o29
i use NetBeans and i have java Version 8 update 45 (build 1.8.0_45-b15)

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. Is your project configured to work with Java 8 compiler and libraries? Can you check values of your project in `properties -> sources -> Source/Binary format` and `properties -> libraries -> java platform`?

Comment: @dekros Yes. This shows that your NetBeans is using Java 7 JDK. To use streams you need to install Java 8 JDK. You will also need to update your NetBeans to version 8.

Comment: ok im make this and checking online stream is work but when i want check status like this     public static String checkStatus(String channel) throws IOException {
        String channerUrl = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + channel;
        String jsonText = readFromUrl(channerUrl);
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonObject json = parser.parse(jsonText).getAsJsonObject();
        return json.get("status").getAsString();
        
    } 
i have this error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
in line  return json.get("status").getAsString();

Comment: That is because as I said, if stream is off-line value of status is `null` and you can't invoke `getAsString` on `null`.

Comment: yes but stream is online link to this stream: https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/disstream and i want get maybe status

Comment: There is no `status` key in this JSON, but `stream` key. To make your work with JSON easier you need to format it properly. You can do it on-line using http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/. Also `stream` will contain JSON object, not String, so `getAsString` will not work. If you want to have string representation of that JSON object use `toString`, but if you want to do some additional processing you can simply use `json.getAsJsonObject("stream")`.

Comment: ok but when i change method to JsonObject and i make this:
        return json.getAsJsonObject("mature");
method return me null but method should return false ;/

Comment: `json` doesn't have `mature` element. Such element is part of object labelled as `channel` which is part of element labelled as `stream` (as long as this object is not null, when stream is off-line). So you need to select `stream` object, check if it is not null, then from it `channel`, and finally read value of `mature`.

Comment: can you give example for this? is my first time with json;//

Comment: It is same as parsing XML or HTML, or any parent-children structure (where children can have their own children). You need to select outer element to get inner element. If you have `parentJsonObject` and you want to get its child JsonObject call `JsonObject child = parentJsonObject.getAsJsonObject("labelOfChildObject")`. In your case parent is `json` object and child will be `stream`. When you get that child and you will make sure that it is not null pick child object of `stream` with label `channel`.

Comment: somethink like this?
JsonObject json = parser.parse(jsonText).getAsJsonObject();
        JsonObject child = json.getAsJsonObject("stream");
        if(child.isJsonNull()){
           return null; 
        }
but how to now return something?
return child.get("display_name").toString();?
im only coding in c++ and java but i beginner in programing

Comment: `display_name` doesn't hold object value. In JSON object is thing inside `{}`, array is represented by contend surrounded by `[` `]`. If value is simple string like `"label": "value"` then you can use `getAsJsonObject` but you need `get(label)`. BTW you should probably read some tutorial about parsing JSON using `gson` library since I can't explain you everything.

Comment: ok sory for spaming etc but is my first time with this.
but i must make this;/ can you give me code to get displayName? when i try child.get/child.getAs etc i have errors or return me null;/

Comment: Your `child` seems to hold object from `stream` label. But `display_name` is part of object from `channel` label, which is part of `stream` object. So you need to get `channel` object and get `display_name` String placed directly in it. So try with `child.getAsJsonObject("channel").get("display_name").getAsString()`.

Comment: You are welcome :) (and based on twitch channels you observe - nie ma sprawy :)